# Show/Hide jPlayer Div

Tags: jquery, html, jplayer

I am trying to figure out how to fade in jPlayer from the top of the page when clicking on a link, and then have it fade out when the song stops playing.

I am still just starting out and I can get jPlayer to work properly, but I am having trouble trying to implement the show/hide feature.

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: How can we help you without your code ?

Comment: Post a code snippet, and I'll take a look.  Fadeins can be done with `$.animate()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#jp_container").hide();

    $.jPlayer.event.play, function() {
        $("#jp_container").slideDown();
    });

    $.jPlayer.event.ended, function() {
        $("#jp_container").slideUp();
    });

});
```